# How to implement search for multiple selection in datatables select box

Tags: jquery, datatables

We have one requirement for multiple selection in select boxes, it is showed below diagram[image]
Please share me your ideas if any,
We tried some code with datatables example
Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select multiple="multiple" id="dummyID"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {                                
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );

        }
    } );
} );
```

Please refer below url [Datatables filtering](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: `we have tried` is not a proper problem statement. You probably want to look into filtering

Comment: I want to implement search functionality for multiple select on the drop down in data tables . I think this statement is correct.